# Inconsitent lighting and colors in threejs

Tags: three.js, gltf

I have been experimenting with threejs for the past few days and have been experiencing inconsistencies in the lighting of my models. So I decided to do a little experiment. Here are side-by-side pictures of scenes containing the same model and the same lighting(`Ambient`, `color: #FFFFFF`, `intensity: 0.3`) one created using javascript and the other using [threejs editor](https://threejs.org/editor/):

- Using threejs editor 
  [image: Model using Threejs Editor]
- Using JS 
  [image: Model using JS]

Why are the colors and lighting different? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have not configured a sRGB workflow in your app. So try it with the following line:

```js
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
```

Comment: Thanks, this made me look at the render settings, I spotted that I had turned on `renderer.physicallyCorrectLights`.